# Open/Close a database from a stream

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to access a SQLite Database from a given Stream (FileStream/Memorystream)?

This is my code so far (it reads the File into a Memorystream and then opens it in SQLite):

```
if (File.Exists(path_DB))
{
    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(path_DB);
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(file);

    using (SQLiteConnection destination = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + mem + ";Version=3;"))
    {
        destination.Open();

        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = destination;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM MyTable;";

            using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(reader["Name"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code triggers me

> SQL Logic error or missing Database, no such table: MyTable

at `command.ExecuteReader()`. The file referred to with `path_DB` does have the table.

Where do I go wrong?

//Edit: Changed

```
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(path_DB);
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
```

to

```
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(path_DB);
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(file);
```

and further I can load an existing Database into the memory one and save the memory DB again to disk like this:

```
if (File.Exists(path_DB))
{
    using (SQLiteConnection destination = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;"))
    {
        SQLiteConnection source = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path_DB + ";Version=3;"); //;Password=" + textBox2.Text + "
        source.Open();

        destination.Open();

        source.BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main", -1, null, 0);
        source.Close();

        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = destination;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM MyTable;";

            using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(reader["Name"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        source = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path_DB + ";Version=3;"); //;Password=" + textBox2.Text + "
        source.Open();

        // save memory db to file
        destination.BackupDatabase(source, "main", "main", -1, null, 0);
        source.Close();
    }
}
```

So I figured, there must be also a way to do this with a direct (decrypted) stream!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code and what you're trying to do.

To start, you're assigning to `file` but not doing anything with it.

Next, you can't just append a `MemoryStream` instance to your connection. As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html):

> The most common way to force an SQLite database to exist purely in memory is to open the database using the special filename ":memory:". In other words, instead of passing the name of a real disk file into one of the sqlite3_open(), sqlite3_open16(), or sqlite3_open_v2() functions, pass in the string ":memory:".

So that means in the connection string, you need `:memory:` as your data source. This is also shown on https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

```
Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;
```

Finally, another snippet from the documentation I earlier referred to:

> When this is done, no disk file is opened. Instead, a new database is created purely in memory. The database ceases to exist as soon as the database connection is closed. Every :memory: database is distinct from every other. So, opening two database connections each with the filename ":memory:" will create two independent in-memory databases.

This means you cannot use an existing database. You create a database, use it and then it's destroyed again. There's no persistence on file level.

If all this makes no sense to you and you just want to use a database that's on your drive, use a connection string like this:

```
Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;
```

The SQLite provider will take care of opening the file, reading from it and writing to it.

For your encryption concerns, [you can use a password for the database](http://web.archive.org/web/20130325100811/http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/130.aspx). This will take care of encrypting the database

```
Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: The thing I read my stream from encrypted content on the disk and then again want to save it encrypted.

Comment: @user3079834 Which library are you using to access the database?

Comment: the SQLite lib I got from nuget (std lib for x86 and x64)

Comment: You just cannot do this flat out. SQLite is an UNMANAGED NATIVE library. It does not know anything about `System.IO.Stream`. It is possible in theory to do this using `Memory Mapped Files` but the resulting mess of interop would make performance a mess.

Comment: However what really confuses me is, that SQLite has an in built encryption API. Why aren't you using that?

Comment: @Aron the SQLite API itself provides no encryption as far as I know, but a library can offer this functionality (which is why I was asking which library OP is using).

Comment: @user3079834 I've added a bit to my answer to show how you can have an encrypted database file.